# Change default outfile location to avoid Error Code 1290 - my.ini not available

Tags: mysql, csv, output

I am trying to export the result of a query to a .csv using:

```
SELECT 'BAT_POSITION_IN_SERIES', 'NUMBER_OF_PITCHES', 'PCT_BALLS', 'PCT_CALLED_STRIKE', 'STRIKEOUTS_PER_PITCH', 'WALKS_PER_PITCH', 'HITS_PER_PITCH', 'RUNS_PER_PITCH'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM per_pitch_summary
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\per_pitch_summary.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
;
```

The above executes, however I would like to change the destination folder.  When replacing the file path with my desired destination, I receive the message: Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

Most of the troubleshooting solutions I have seen involve commenting out a line in the my.ini file, but I do not have this file in my version of MySQL.  Instead, the Path to Executable is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have a default config file somewhere.  But you can specify your own config when launching sql.  The following will load the default options but override the ones set in your config, this is the safer option.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/home/my.cnf
```

Then in your **my.cnf**:

```
[client]
user="root"
password="mypassword"
host="localhost"
database="placeToStart"

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

By setting it to an empty path you'll disable the variable.  To confirm this, look at the global variable value:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

Comment: Thanks, @Phaelax z, however I do not see the my.cnf file either.  And when I look for the .csv file that supposedly was successfully created here: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads, I cannot even see the Uploads folder.  Perhaps I don't have the correct privileges set up to view/access these files?

Comment: well the my.cnf in my example is a file YOU create.  But it is also possible you lack the privileges to the other files/location. Do you have admin rights on that windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I do (it's a personal machine).  That said, something is happening behind the scenes that I can't see, because when I re-execute the above query, I receive a notification that the file already exists: Error Code: 1086. File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\per_pitch_summary.csv' already exists, even though I can't see it.